# Authenticate shopify from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, authentication, shopify

So the idea is to give users of the current asp.net application access to the shop without them having to register again.

Are there any design considerations here, would it be bad practice to bypass the default shopify auth, or would it be a bad user experience to register twice.

Has anyone implemented 3rd party auth to shopify successfully?

Comment: if you know that the user is registered on shopify, just create an asp.net authorize cookie.

Comment: Its the other way around the user is already registered in asp.net, not shopify

Comment: I do not know how shopify - look at their manual if they let you do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is an option for the Shopify Plus users. If you already have some application and wants to allow your users to access Shopify without logging in again you can use **Multipass**. According to [Shopify website](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/plus/multipass)

> Multipass login is for store owners who have a separate website and a
>   Shopify store. It redirects users from the website to the Shopify
>   store and seamlessly logs them in with the same email address they
>   used to sign up for the original website. If no account with that
>   email address exists yet, one is created. There is no need to
>   synchronize any customer databases.

This is a standard option from Shopify so cannot be considered a bad pratcice and you don't have to consider any other options like security conisderations etc. Just implement Multipass login using standard recommendations in documentation.

Comment: The only downside being that plus is very expensive, maybe a custom wordpress implementation would be a better option